# swagger editor error : CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing

Tags: jersey, cors, swagger, swagger-ui

I have generated the swagger.json from my jersey project and trying to test it locally on swagger editor but I am getting the well known error on the 'try it out' for each api : CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing
EVEN THOUGH I have added the required headers for each request:

**java code**

```
public Response getObject(@PathParam("name")String name) {

        ....
                return Response.ok(myObect)
                .header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
                .header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true")
                .header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD")
                .header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "origin, content-type, accept, authorization").build();
        }
```

**generated swagger**

```
'/object/{name}':
    get:
      consumes:
        - application/json
      produces:
        - text/html
      parameters:
        - type: string
          name: name
          in: path
          required: true
      responses:
        '200':
          description: OK
          headers:
            Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:
              type: string
            Access-Control-Allow-Headers:
              type: string
            Access-Control-Allow-Methods:
              type: string
            Access-Control-Allow-Origin:
              type: string
```

by the way, I am running the project on tomcat 8.5 and swagger on Wamp server, I hope that does not make any difference

Answer (score 1):

I think this might be something to do with your server rather than the code itself!

```
wampmanager -> Apache -> Apache modules -> headers_module
```

Try to enable CORS on your WAMP server first.

Comment: that unfortunately did not work.. any other module to check?

Comment: The issue will definitely be server related rather than the code itself. Did you restart all services once you enabled CORS through the above steps.

Comment: yes I have restarted the wamp server and cleared the cash from the browser but still the same